# Accidentally deleted client side repository + dir structure. RSA key no longer works

Tags: git, github

Running Ubuntu. Accidentally deleted directory structure with multiple repositories.  Cloned repositories from github (all up to date), and brought them back to life onto my local machine.

**Issue:** 
Rsa key no longer works with git hub. Key exists in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

`$ ssh -T git@github.com` gives me:
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but Github does
not provide shell access.

When i attempt to push to github:
Error:  fatal: unable to connect to cache daemon: Permission denied
Username for 'https://github.com':

GitHub asks for username / password.  Auth goes through successfully but returns

`Error:  fatal: unable to connect to cache daemon: Permission denied.`

Git then pushes successfully.

======================================================================

Worked through github docs and stackoverflow related artices to no avail. This solution looked to be promising but upon running it:

`sudo chown -R user:user ~/.git-credential-cache/`

chown: cannot access '/root/.git-credential-cache/': No such file or directory

Also, attempted to make new key with new name per github docs. Result was the same.

=========================================================================

I would like to auth to github with the rsa key that i made!

Comment: Why not just re-clone the repos from scratch? (Also, have you tried turning it off and on again? The errors about a demon sounds like you've ended up in an inconsistent state that might clear up if you log out and back in -- or reboot).

Comment: figured it out...somehow the the config file flipped the url to https:// instead of git@github.com:username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: .git config file flipped the url to https:// instead of git@github.com:username